# in createFile method templateArr shows null. why?

Tags: java

It is a class with 3 method and i simply use all 3 through main method.
i get a template file
then i get a file with content
and then i create another files using the content and template.
but it is not working as it show that templateArr is null.
because in the eclipse it cannot find the suitable files.

```
package collegejava;
import java.io.*;

public class MailMerge {

    String data="",template="",arr;
    String fileArr [],templateArr []=new String[3];
    public void getFile1(String fileName1){
        try {
            File f1 = new File(fileName1 +"txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
            while((data=br.readLine())!=null){
                template +=data;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void getFile2(String fileName2){
        try {
            File f1 = new File(fileName2 +"txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
            int i=0;
            while((arr=br.readLine())!=null){
                fileArr = arr.split("\\t");
                templateArr[i] = template.replaceAll("<name>",fileArr[0]);//HERE AM ASSIGNING STRING TO TEMPLATEARR.
                i++;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void createFile(){
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<templateArr.length;i++){ //THIS LINE SHOWS THAT TEMPLATEARR IS NULL
                File f = new File("MailMerged.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(templateArr[i]);
                bw.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be something else than `null`? Where do you assign something to it?

Comment: `String templateArr [];` is a non-primitive instance variable, therefore its value will be `null` by default. You have to initialize it somewhere.